# Accessing the Yelp Api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, yelp

In my application I have to add a button, and display the number of stars received from `YELP` as shown in this image: [image], and upon clicking it I should navigate to a new View that will show the Yelp reviews.

1.) I have read the [Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api), and was unable to find a way to append the `Store Name` to get its ratings in Yelp.

For example: I need to get the YELP ratings of `Agra Indian Restaurant`, so how should I get the `JSON` return values pertaining to `Agra Indian Restaurant`?

Is there any tutorial or sample code that illustrates how I could get this done?

Answer (score 3):

You can get some examples form here:https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/ .I used php examples.Since the Search Parameters doesn`t contain the store name, you can using the business name as the "term" query parameter and the full business address as the "location"
parameter.

It's worth noting that if you know the business you're looking for specifically, you're
better off using the Phone API to look up info directly.